# How to set value of second calender by the value of first calender

Tags: calendar

I have two calenders on asp.net form. If the first calender is set to a date, then the second calender will have to set to that date and all previous dates of second calender should be disabled automatically. Please help.
Thanks for reading...

Comment: You must tell us, what you've tried and if you can share some code snippet it'll be a lot easier to understand what's exactly the problem is.

Comment: I have following code on my first calender's render event:-     protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) < 0)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        }
    }  But it disables only the previous dates than today, but I want to disable dates of second calender based on first calender's selection. For eg. If user selects 15 march 2014 on first calender then all the dates before 15 march 2014 on second calender should be disabled. Please help